# Two Dimension Array of size 10

Tags: arrays, input, multidimensional-array, pseudocode

starting with programming and would like tips on writing pseudocode for a 2 Dimension array in a main class that stores usernames and passwords for each account.

Program should take a username input, store it in the array - preferbly using a function(Function that adds usernames and passwords or different functions adding each seperately), and then a password store it in a correspoding dimension to the user name enter - for an array sizeof 10: ArraySize(10)(10) all

Should be able to login(Account Search Function - could search both password and function using the same function or two function searching each part separetly) to the account with check of password combination(Function that checks password limit = 3)

Should be able to delete. So login first, and then delete an invidual account.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Java but would like a pseudocode more structured like a programming language so that I can transfer it to any programming language @phil652

Comment: Welcome to SO, normally people won't do the work for. Give it a try post what you think would work then we can help you correct what doesn't work